# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context on php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /home2/property/teampropertyhunter.com/wp-content/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/lite/includes/admin/wp-site-health.php on line 106

```
public function is_tracking() {

    if ( ! isset( $this->is_tracking ) ) {
        $this->is_tracking = ! empty( monsterinsights_get_ua() );
    }

    return $this->is_tracking;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In php < 5.5 (thanks to @jszobody for pointing that out), you can't run checks like `empty()` on a function's return. You can solve it (at least) two different ways:

Assign the value to a variable before checking:

```
if ( ! isset( $this->is_tracking ) ) {
    $monsterUA = monsterinsights_get_ua();
    $this->is_tracking = ! empty( $monsterUA );
}
```

or, just use the presence of a value and a ternary operator:

```
if ( ! isset( $this->is_tracking ) ) {
    $this->is_tracking = monsterinsights_get_ua() ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Comment: You can as of php 5.5. Docs say for 5.5.0 "empty() now supports expressions, rather than only variables." Sounds like OP is running php 5.4 or earlier.

Comment: @jszobody I guess my age is showing, hah. I was bit by the `empty()` issue a few times and just never used it that way again!

Comment: Yeah I'm assuming this code is part of a WP plugin, not something the OP wrote himself. Plugin author probably doesn't intend to support really php versions.